# akka-http apply javax.servlet.Filter

Tags: java, scala, servlets, akka-http

How does one add a class that implements interface [javax.servlet.Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) into an Akka-http service, for instance the example one [AkkaHttpMicroservice](https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice/blob/master/src/main/scala/AkkaHttpMicroservice.scala#L107) below:

```
object AkkaHttpMicroservice extends App with Service {
  override implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  override implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
  override implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  override val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  override val logger = Logging(system, getClass)

  Http().bindAndHandle(routes, config.getString("http.interface"), config.getInt("http.port"))
}
```

In Scalatra, one needs to `override def init(context: ServletContext)`, then `context.addFilter("mySecurityFilter", SecurityFilter)`, but its not clear where the `ServletContext` is accessible in akka-http.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately for you Akka-Http is not based on the standard Java Servlet API. Actually the whole HTTP handling is re-implemented from the level of the TCP connection. This is done to fully use the power of Akka/Akka Streams. However it means that you can not apply `javax.servlet.Filter` to Akka-based application. What you probably want to used instead is [Directives](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/index.html).